# SmsRetrieverHelper SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17499 Error code:39 - Flutter - Firebase Phone Authentication - OTP

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to enable Firebase Phone Authentication on this app using Flutter and Dart
but every time I put any number that is not a test number the Recaptcha screen appears then this error appears:

```
[SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status code: 17499 Error code:39
```

on the other hand, when I try a number that is a test number everything goes well

here is the **AuthController** that handles the verification process:

```
class AuthController extends GetxController{
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  var verificationId = ''.obs;
  TextEditingController phoneController = TextEditingController();
  var otp = '';
  var _resendToken;

  Future<void> phoneAuthentication(String phone) async{

    await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phone,

      verificationCompleted: (credential) {},
      codeSent: (verificationId, resendToken){
        this.verificationId.value = verificationId;
        this._resendToken = resendToken;
        debugPrint('code is sent');
        Get.toNamed(Verification.routeName);
      },
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 120),
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId){
        this.verificationId.value = verificationId;
      },
      verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e){
        debugPrint('error message: ${e.message}');
        debugPrint('error code: ${e.code}');
        debugPrint('error stackTrace: ${e.stackTrace}');
        showCustomToast(msg: 'sending failed error code: ${e.code}');
      },
      forceResendingToken: this._resendToken,
    );
  }

  Future<void> verifyOTP(String otp) async{

    try {
      PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
          verificationId: verificationId.value, smsCode: otp);
      UserCredential user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
      debugPrint('${credential.smsCode}: credential.smsCode');

      if (user.user != null) {
        Get.offAndToNamed(Home.routeName);
      }
    }
    catch (e){
      showCustomToast(msg: 'wrong code');
    }
  }

}
```

and this is **my app/build.gradle**:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 33
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.phone_store"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 33
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.1.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.5.0'
}

configurations.all {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-safetynet'
}
```

this is my **android/build.gradle**:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Here are my depedencies in my **pubspec.yaml**:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
  otp_text_field: ^1.1.1
  flutter_carousel_slider: ^1.0.8
  intl_phone_number_input: ^0.7.0+2
  cached_network_image: ^3.2.0
  shimmer: ^2.0.0
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.0.1
  firebase_core:
  firebase_auth:
  cloud_firestore:
  flutter_smart_dialog:
  get:
```

I have connected my app with Firebase **SHA-1** and also **SHA-256**, I ensured that the phone authentication is **enabled** in the Firebase console, I also Enabled **Google Play  Integrity API** in Google Cloud and made sure that my app check is **registered** and downloaded the latest version of **Google.service.json**, and I did not forget to try to upgrade my dependencies to the latest version

please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The old solutions are no longer valid. The links given above are no longer valid.

The main reasons for this are that some APIs in the Google Console are no longer available. For example Android Device Verification.

Therefore, I present the new solution.

Add this if you haven't already. It will help you solve some problems during the development phase.

Android -> app -> src -> debug -> AndroidManifest.xml

Android -> app -> src -> main -> AndroidManifest.xml

add to 15th line. usesClearTextTraffic;"true"

[image]

Open cloud console (cloud.google.com/apis/) and click **Credentials** menu on left panel.

[image]

Click **IOS** and **Android** Edit API Key

[image]

fill this areas:
[image]

you can see SHA-1 key:
open terminal and write this for mac os

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

Click **Save**
[image]

Repeat the same process for Android Key.

That's all, you should no longer see the **17499** error.

Comment: why you add android app to ios  key?

Comment: @HassanHallak We do not add it to the iOS key.