# Is Firebase phone Auth working with out google play account?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication

I do not have a Google Play account yet, and I am trying to use Firebase phone auth., and getting this error (missing-client-identifier) and (app-not-authorized). "note: before working fine".
so, I have done some research and what I understood is I need a Google Play account, is that correct?

```
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-playintegrity")
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-appcheck-debug")
```

```
release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
```

```
  firebase_core: ^2.24.2
  firebase_database: ^10.3.8
  firebase_auth: ^4.15.3
  firebase_app_check: ^0.2.1+6
```

```
await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    androidProvider: AndroidProvider.debug,
    webProvider: ReCaptchaV3Provider('recaptcha-v3-site-key'),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Having a google play account is not related to this errors,

Make sure the API key and SHA certificate fingerprint in your firebase project sittings are correct.

Comment: I am sure they are correct. but, Is the SHA case sensitive? I copy SHA1 and past it in my project but it changed to lower case, but in the console remains same.

Comment: Yes, it's case sensitive

Comment: I changed them both in lowercase. but, now I am getting new error (unknown status code: 17499 Error code:39). It is really driving me crazy!

Comment: did you check this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76386725/smsretrieverhelper-sms-verification-code-request-failed-unknown-status-code-17

Answer (score 0):

> Is Firebase phone Auth working without a Google Play account?

Yes, you can authenticate to Firebase using phone authentication without a Google Play account. However, if you need to authenticate in Firebase with Google, then indeed you'll need the [Google Play services library](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin#before_you_begin).

Comment: thanks for your help, but I already followed these steps. now I changed my SHA all in lowercase same in project and in console and I am getting now this error (unknown status code: 17499 Error code:39)

Comment: It sounds like you should ask another question that explains what exactly isn't working the way you expect and is the exact code that produces that error.

Comment: Can I help you with other information regarding the initial question?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your attention and help, I solved The main problem by making both SHA in console and project in lower case.

Comment: But your question was related to authenticating to Firebase using phone authentication without a Google Play account. So did my answer help?

Comment: your Answer to the main question (yes it helped me) but, there is details in the question "the error message". I really really appreciate your attention and support.